# How do I add percentage in horizontal bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, which creates a horizontal bar chart:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('C:/py/matplotlib/02-BarCharts/data.csv')
responders_id = data['Responder_id']
langs_worked_with = data['LanguagesWorkedWith']

languages = Counter()
for reponse in langs_worked_with:
    languages.update(reponse.split(";"))

langs = []
langs_users_num = []

for language in languages.most_common(15):
    langs.append(language[0])
    langs_users_num.append(language[1])

langs.reverse()
langs_users_num.reverse()

plt.barh(langs, langs_users_num)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and after running above code I get this:

[image]

the data which represents this chart is parsed from stackoverflow and the same chart in stackoverflow looks like below. How do I modify above code to add percentage as shown below.

[image]

Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I chose some sample data. The idea is

- Create new y-tick labels by adding the name of the language and the percentage
- Assign these modified labels on the y-axis
- Hide the frame and the x-axis of the figure together with the y-axis ticks

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

total = 90000
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python']
langs_users_num = np.array([32000, 40000, 50000, 60000])

percent = langs_users_num/total*100

new_labels = [i+'  {:.2f}%'.format(j) for i, j in zip(langs, percent)]

plt.barh(langs, langs_users_num, color='lightskyblue', edgecolor='blue')
plt.yticks(range(len(langs)), new_labels)
plt.tight_layout()

for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)

ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", left=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I just run this in my code and it worked as expected. 
can you please explain line#3, line#8 (new_labels)

Comment: Using zip you iterate over the two lists together and then add the language name plus some whitespace plus the percentage using format up to 2 decimal places

Comment: what is `total=90000`?

Comment: The number I took to calculate percentages. Just to give an answer

Comment: I didn't understand. 
How did you get this number, I added items of langs_users_num but that is not 90000? How did you calculate it?

Comment: That’s just a large number. You didn’t provide anything to compute so I just took something.

Comment: @BasirPayenda : For coloring few tick labels, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165402/4932316) answer with an if statement inside the list comprehension. Or check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878462/matplotlib-changing-the-color-of-a-single-x-axis-tick-label) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997934/change-color-of-specific-ticks-at-plot-with-matplotlib). If they don;t solve your problem, as a new question