# Highlight certain barplot label

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have this horizontal barplot and I want to highlight certain labels (or keywords) with other colors.
This is my horizontal barplot:
[image]

I want to make the keyword 'nature' and 'panorama' to be red color. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)                    # tight layout
plt.barh(df['keywords'], df['number'])                              # base barplot with blue color
plt.barh(df[df['keywords']=='nature'], df['number'], color='red')   # overlay barplot with red color
plt.barh(df[df['keywords']=='panorama'], df['number'], color='red') # overlay barplot with red color
ax.tick_params(labelsize=18)
plt.title('Difference average of cluster 3')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib - Changing the color of a single x-axis tick label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878462/matplotlib-changing-the-color-of-a-single-x-axis-tick-label)

Comment: it's not actually. because it takes the position of the label, while I want to highlight the label based on the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to add two columns, namely 'number_red','number_blue':

```
df['number_red']=np.where((df['keywords']=='nature')|(df['keywords']=='panorama'),df['number'],0)
df['number_blue']=np.where((df['keywords']!='nature')&(df['keywords']!='panorama'),df['number'],0)
```

'number_red' only show numbers that belong to 'panorama' or 'nature', while fill numbers of keywords with zero. 'number_blue' does the opposite. (You can print df to have a look) 
So if you just overlay these two columns in your bar plot:

```
plt.barh(df['keywords'],df['number_red'],  color='red')
plt.barh(df['keywords'],df['number_blue'], color='blue')
```

The numbers will be complementary, but show you the desired color. I hope this helps!

Comment: I changed the last two codes to `plt.barh(df['number_red'],  df['number'], color='red')` so that it can plot the the right column. But the y-axis now showing the number instead of the keywords.

Comment: Hi I changed the last two codes in the answer, so that it should set column 'keywords' as bar name. (while the previous code set integer (0,1,2...) as bar name). Please let me know if it works now!

Comment: indeed @tianlinhe ... it works very well now. thanks