# Change color of specific ticks at plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, is there an option to change the color of specific **tick labels** on the axis?

I have a simple plot that show some values by days, and I need to mark some days as 'special' day so I want to mark these with a different color but not all ticks just some specific.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Formatting only selected tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924963/formatting-only-selected-tick-labels)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can get a list of tick labels using [`ax.get_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html). This is actually a list of text objects. As a result, you can use [`set_color()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_color) on an element of that list to change the color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
ax.plot([1,2,3])

ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_color("red")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can get the current axes using `plt.gca()`. The below code will give the same result

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])

plt.gca().get_xticklabels()[3].set_color("red")

plt.show()
```

Comment: What if I also want to change the color of the small tick above the number 0.50?

Comment: this will do the trick

xTicks = plt.xticks(np.arange(3)) ; 

xTicks[0][2]._apply_params(color='r') ; 

plt.show()