# Change Parameters of individual xtick Labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have more control over individual x-axis labels using matplotlib. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997934/change-color-of-specific-ticks-at-plot-with-matplotlib) helped me a bit, but I still would like to do more. For instance I would like to bold, change font style and font size.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot(x,y)
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_color('red')
```

[image]

I do understand with something like the following line, I have more parameters to control, but this will change all the labels, not an individual one:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=45, weight='light')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use all the functionalities

```
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_color('red')
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_fontsize(20)
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_weight("bold")
ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_rotation(45)
```

The bold function does work. See the difference:

[image]

[image]